# Implications of time reversibility in the initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, time-reversal-symmetry

I read somewhere the following statement: In a partial differential equation (PDE) in order to get the property of time reversibility in your solutions, you need to set the initial condition $u'=0$ (time derivative equal to zero).

Specifically, they were talking about sine-Gordon equation. In order to numerically solve the equation, space discretization was employed and then an ODE solver was used.

My question is: why does setting $u'=0$ provide time reversibility?

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with a straightforward answer (FWIW, I think the questioner is confusing reversibility with time *symmetry*).

Answer (score 0):

Odd order time derivatives change sign when reversing time. The solutions with:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}|_{t=0}=v
$$
and
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}|_{t=0}=-v
$$
are not identical... unless $v=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the sine-Gordon equation involves second-order time derivatives, so I guess there should be another reason...

Comment: @PenilinLot *the solution is determined not only by the equation, but by the initial conditions*. E.g., if it is an initial value problem for a  an n-th order ODE, it depends on n constants - the initial value of the function and the initial values for derivatives up to (n-1)-th. If you change the sign of these constants you select another solution: $t\longrightarrow -t\Rightarrow y(t;x_0,v_0)\longrightarrow y(t;x_0, -v_0)$

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a justification for the statement as you report it.
The time reversibility of a second-order differential equation, like sine-Gordon, does not depend on the initial conditions but on the structure of the equation.

Even if we start with a zero initial first derivative, in general, the time evolution of the field does not conserve the first derivative and then, such a condition is not generic.

The time reversibility means that if we invert the sign of the first derivative with respect to time at some time $T$, the following evolution of the system re-traces in a reversed order, from time $T$ to time $2T$, all the configurations appeared from time $0$ to time $T$.